# Easiest way to get a Fedora VM on my Ubuntu machine?

Tags: linux, fedora, lvm

What's the easiest way to get a Fedora VM on my Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward approach would be to install [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and then grab a Fedora .iso and load up a virtualbox client.

Or you could install [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) and grab a [pre-built Fedora "appliance"](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/cat/0?k=fedora).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to install new VMs from the .ISO. That way I can customize the install, mainly by leaving out things that I won't need in the VM. That way I have a more compact system. The VMs still take up real hard drive space.

For real production use, I would want to use XEN but that is definitely not an easy choice. Even though there is some powerful XEN management software out there, you still have to figure out which one to use. Virtualbox OSE is far easier because it is distributed a single package with a straightforward GUI to set up and manage your VMs. So to meet your "easiest" criteria, it has to be Virtualbox.